# Undefined type error even with forward declaration

Tags: c++, header-files, forward-declaration, circular-reference

I was reading up on circular references and forward declarations. I do understand that it is not a good design practice to have implementations in a header file. However I was experimenting and could not understand this behavior.

With the following code (containing the forward declarations) I expected it to build, however I get this error:

```
Error   1   error C2027: use of undefined type 'sample_ns::sample_class2'
```

Header.hpp

```
#ifndef HEADER_HPP
#define HEADER_HPP
#include "Header2.hpp"
namespace sample_ns
{
    class sample_class2;
    class sample_class{
    public:
        int getNumber()
        {       
            return sample_class2::getNumber2();
        }
    };
}
#endif
```

Header2.hpp

```
#ifndef HEADER2_HPP
#define HEADER2_HPP
#include "Header.hpp"
namespace sample_ns
{
    class sample_class;
    class sample_class2{
    public:
        static int getNumber2()
        {
            return 5;
        }
    };
}
#endif
```

Obviously I am missing on something. Can someone point me in the right direction as to why am I getting this error.

Comment: `sampele_class` => `sample_class` as far you've posted your real code here, which you're required to.

Comment: Was experimenting with the code and made a typo.

Comment: Separate declaration from definition. See this please:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can only get away with forward declare if you have pointers or references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration). Since you are using a specific method of that class, you need a full include.

However with your current design, you have a circular dependency. Change your Header2 file to remove the `"Header.hpp"` and forward declare of `sample_class` to resolve the circular dependency.

```
#ifndef HEADER2_HPP
#define HEADER2_HPP
namespace sample_ns
{
    class sample_class2{
    public:
        static int getNumber2()
        {
            return 5;
        }
    };
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Also, is there any workaround to get this kind of design to work without moving the implementations to a cpp file (keeping the circular dependency, i.e lets say I have to use an object of sample_class in Header2).

Comment: *"Lets say I need to have a circular dependency."* Then you are dead in the water. It is, by definition, impossible to compile code that has a circular dependency.

Comment: I'll probably move the definitions to cpp file. thanks

Comment: @CoryKramer, no, it is impossible to have a aggregate circular dependency.  I.e. You cannot have a full class object inside of another full class object.  Make one a pointer and you resolve the problem.

Comment: @Adrian Which was literally the first line of my answer. But this is not a circular dependency at that point.