# Issue with circular dependency even after separating definitions

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

Please see my previous post here:

[Undefined type error even with forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701467/undefined-type-error-even-with-forward-declaration)

I moved the definitions to cpp files and I still face the issue. Any ideas why? My files look like this:

Header1.hpp

```
#ifndef HEADER1_HPP
#define HEADER1_HPP

namespace sample_ns
{
    class sample_class{
    public:
        static int getNumber();
        static void print();    
    };
}
#endif
```

Header2.hpp

```
#ifndef HEADER2_HPP
#define HEADER2_HPP
namespace sample_ns
{
    class sample_class2{
    public:
        sample_class2();
        int getNumber2();
    };
}

#endif
```

Source1.cpp

```
#include "Header1.hpp"
#include "Header2.hpp"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
namespace sample_ns
{
        int sample_class::getNumber()
        {
            sample_class2 obj;
            return obj.getNumber2();
        }
        void sample_class::print()
        {
            std::cout << "Print utility function" << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Source2.cpp

```
#include "Header2.hpp"
#include "Header1.hpp"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
namespace sample_ns
{
        sample_class2::sample_class2()
        {
            sample_class::print();
        }
        int sample_class2::getNumber2()
        {
            sample_class::print();
            return 5;
        }
}
```

In my main I call it as:

```
 std::cout << sample_ns::sample_class::getNumber() << std::endl;
```

I get 'sample_class2' : undeclared identifier. I tried adding `class sample_class2;` but that still gives me error

EDIT:
my main file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Header1.hpp"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    std::cout << sample_ns::sample_class::getNumber() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does main.cpp look like?

Comment: I think you should just use "using namespace sample_ns" in the cpp files instead of defining the functions in that namespace. It maybe won't fix the issue, but it is good style.

Comment: It works well for me...

Comment: It works fine for me. I can compile it. Please show, how you are actually invoking your compiler.

Comment: The files are part of VS console application project. I just build the solution

Comment: Your code runs fine for me if I just take out the stdafx.h from both source files and make change main to int main()

Comment: Thanks for that comment. Looks like some issue with precompiled headers. disabling that fixed the errors. Will look into precompiled headers now.

Comment: The precompiled headers are the stdafx.h aren't they?

Comment: I am not completely sure about the precompiled headers. Will read more about them now. However, removing stdafx.h from source1 and source2, disabling precompiled headers option in project properties fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for declaring classes and namespaces in header and cpp files is using structure likes below:

Header1.hpp

```
#ifndef HEADER1_HPP
#define HEADER1_HPP
#include "Header2.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace sample_ns
{
    class sample_class{
    public:
        static int getNumber();
        static void print();    
    };
}
#endif
```

Source1.cpp

```
#include "Header1.hpp"
namespace sample_ns
{
        int sample_class::getNumber()
        {
            sample_class2 obj;
            return obj.getNumber2();
        }
        void sample_class::print()
        {
            std::cout << "Print utility function" << std::endl;
        }
}
```

So by including in header files and using ifndef you become sure that circular dependencies will not occure.

Comment: `stdafx.h` does not belong in a header file and your headers are including themselves.

Comment: You are recursively including Header1.hpp in Header1.hpp

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, this runs perfectly fine for me if I take out the stdafx.h from both source files and change the entry to int main() or int main(int argc, char arg[])